# C# install kernel driver to protect files

Tags: c#

I'm creating a simple AntiVirus application. I read that commercial AntiVirus apps are protecting their files against edition or deletion by installing kernel driver to OS. I also want to use that method. Is there any way to do that using C# (if is, tell me how) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can't run managed .NET code at the kernel level as drivers. You'll have to write the driver in unmanaged code in C or C++ (beware that C++ support is limited to a subset of C++ that is very close to plain C).

What you need is probably a [file system filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).